# Do Postgresql sequences work with SDE versioning?

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I am migrating data from an older GIS system into an SDE system with PostgreSQL as the database engine.  The current system generates a unique tag for several layers, I want to re-create this behavior using sequences in the PostgreSQL database.  I have it working in a single user environment, but will it work in a versioned environment?  Right now the field is populated by using Postgres' nextval() function as the field's default value.  When the tables are versioned do those defaults go with them?

Comment: SDE no longer exists. The current term of art is "enterprise geodatabase". Sequences continue to work, but you need to study the implementation details to determine *where* the sequence should live. It may not be technically be supported to modify the `An` table to use a default value from a sequence, and it may be a bit of a challenge to prevent that column from being populated on an insert, but you can achieve your goal.  But no, I don't believe the defaults will be inherited (and they need to be disabled from the base tables after versioning).

Comment: As far as I know a Postgres sequence can be called from anywhere by anyone who has permission to use it.  It can live in any schema.

Comment: Certainly it can live in any schema, but it's dangerous to place it in any schema other than where it will be used. The schema is not my concern; it's the table from which it's invoked which is the issue. Note too that the Adds table is used for UPDATEs as well as INSERTs, so you cannot use a UNIQUE key.

Answer (score 1):

I made some tests on a similar topic using Oracle, and it was not a real success. I played with the base table and the A table, adding an auto-generated unique key. It is important to stress that the uniqueness was enforced by a constraint.

I faced two issues (from the top of my head, it's a bit old): One that could be overcome, that made new records created in ArcMap have a Null value instead of the default sequence value, and saving this record would fail.

The second issue was more perverse, as it would occurred when duplicating a record. The current value would also be duplicated, creating a unique constraint error.

The only way I found at that time to have an independent sequence with a unique key was to make use of Oracle *hidden column* with an *identity column*. This new column would not be visible in ArcMap and was ignored when creating a new record. Of course ESRI said they didn't support it and therefore didn't recommend using it.